# Capturing number from HTML text

Tags: javascript

I want to capture phone numbers from an HTML document. I have used a pattern but its also selecting numbers that are the part of attributes of tags.

```
var myArray = $('body').html().match(/([\s()-.])*(0[1-9]|[+][1-9]|[+][+][1-9]|00[1-9])(([\s()-.\/])*[0-9]+)*/g);
```

Comment: This is why it doesn't understand the HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html()` method in jQuery uses the `innerHTML` JavaScript property.
The `innerHTML` property retrieves the source of an element at runtime.
If you need the pure text content of an element (without HTML tags), use the `innerText` and `textContent` properties.

Example:

```
var bodyText = (document.body.textContent === undefined) ? document.body.innerText : document.body.textContent;
var myArray = bodyText().match (/([\s()-.])*(0[1-9]|[+][1-9]|[+][+][1-9]|00[1-9])(([\s()-.\/])*[0-9]+)*/g);
```

For further details and examples:[innerText property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhvexii.php), [textContent property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljermebq.php), [innerHTML property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdkwhqf.php).